# Safest Place For My Oud!

Tags: theory, tuning, sound

quick question, can i keep my Oud in the basement?

i live in Chicago and it gets little cold here in the winter. i was told that the humid will ruin the wood of the Oud, which it makes sense to me, but i would like to hear that from a pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is wood and anything like a guitar humidity or dryness can both be bad.

Winter will be cold and dry, summer hot and humid.

there are products that could easily work for any wood instrument such as the "The D’Addario Two-Way Humidification System".

> Using patented technology, the D’Addario Two-Way Humidification System features disposable, moisture-filled packets with a breathable membrane that provides two-way humidity control, meaning it can either release or absorb moisture to consistently maintain a predetermined relative humidity (RH) level of 45-50 percent.

check out [this page](https://www.taylorguitars.com/support/maintenance/using-guitar-humidifier) for some good info, including how to see if a guitar is too dry or too wet, that may or may not help with the oud. more info about the two way humidification system is on that page too.